# If $x-a$, $y-a$, and $z-a$ are in Geometric Progression, prove that $2(y-a)$ is the harmonic mean between $y-x$ and $y-z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x-a$, $y-a$, and $z-a$ are in Geometric Progression, prove that $2(y-a)$ is the harmonic mean between $y-x$ and $y-z$.

Geometric Progression: $\dfrac{z-a}{y-a}=\dfrac{y-a}{x-a} \Rightarrow (y-a)^2=(x-a)(z-a)$

$y-x$, $2(y-a)$, $y-z$ are in Harmonic Progression. Their reciprocals are in Arithmetic Progression: $\dfrac{1}{y-x}$, $\dfrac{1}{2(y-a)}$, $\dfrac{1}{y-z}$.

Hence the Arithmetic Mean is:
$\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{1}{y-x}+\dfrac{1}{y-z})  = \dfrac{1}{2(y-a)} \Rightarrow \dfrac{2y-x-z}{(y-x)(y-z)}=\dfrac{1}{y-a}$

$\Rightarrow (2y-x-z)(y-a)=y^2-xy-yz+xz$

$\Rightarrow 2y^2-2ay-xy+ax-yz+az=y^2-xy-yz+xz$

$\Rightarrow y^2-2ay+ax+az-xz=0$

Since $(y-a)^2=(x-a)(z-a) \Rightarrow y^2+a^2-2ay=xz-ax-az+a^2 \Rightarrow y^2-2ay = xz-ax-az$

$\Rightarrow y^2=2ay+xz-ax-az$

Substituting $y^2$:

$2ay+xz-ax-az-2ay+ax+az-xz=0$ Which is indeed equal to zero.

Is this a valid proof? Or in other words I feel I'm just plugging in values into a formula and showing both sides are equivalent to zero. I'm also not sure if it is appropriate for me to use $2(y-a)$ because that is what the question wants me to *prove*, ie. the end result, whereas I just grabbed it and did calculations with it right from the start. In fact I wouldn't know how to do the calculation without it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's very common in proofs to construct it going one direction as a rough draft.  Then simply recopy the whole proof reversing the steps alongside other modifications like defining variables before they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows: since the result we expect depends only on $y$ and $a$ one trick is to try to rewrite $y-x$ and $y-z$ based on those values. Specifically since we have a geometric progression we can say that $y-a = r*(x-a)$, or equivalently $x-a = \frac{y-a}{r}$, for some factor $r \neq 0$, and similarly for $z$ (we have $z-a = r*(y-a)$). Looking at these results we can reason in various ways to get to a suitable rewrite of $y-x$ and $y-z$, I will take the first as an exmaple.

We can see that the main relation regarding both $x$ and $y$ is $y-a = r*(x-a)$, or equivalently $x-a = \frac{y-a}{r}$. At this point one strategy may be to get $x-a$ into our $y-x$ formula, rebalancing as needed to preserve the equality, i.e. $y-x = y - (x-a) - a$ where we added $a$ at the end. This is kinda equivalent to the trick of adding some null quantity to an equation, in our case this is $(a-a)=0$. An alternative would be to further work on the geometric relation formula, deriving $x$ directly. In this case we would get $x = \frac{y-a}{r} + a$, which can be plugged directly into our difference $y-x=y- \frac{y-a}{r} - a = (y-a)(1 - \frac{1}{r}) $. In the following I use the first line of reasoning which makes the formulas a bit cleaner.

$$y-x = (y-a) - (x-a) = (y-a) - \frac{y-a}{r} = \frac{(y-a)(r-1)}{r}$$

$$y-z = (y-a) - (z-a) = (y-a) - r*(y-a) = (y-a)(1-r)$$

At this point we can simply write the Harmonic mean formula using the derived values.

$$\frac{2}{\frac{1}{y-x} + \frac{1}{y-z}} = \frac{2}{\frac{r}{(y-a)(r-1)} + \frac{1}{(y-a)(1-r)}} = \frac{2}{\frac{r-1}{(y-a)(r-1)}} = 2(y-a)$$

Which is the expected result.
This way we did not use the result it self in the formulas, but we derive it entirely from scratch. Note however that looking at the expected result was the key in getting the intuition on how to build the proof.

To comment on your proof, I would not say it is wrong, indeed you showed that the equality holds since it does not lead to any contrraddiction. However I would say that it is less general, meaning that it used some information which may not be available in some other scenarios. As an example you can take a slightly modified question where you are asked to prove that "the harmonic mean of $y-x$ and $y-z$ can be defined in terms of $y-a$".

Comment: I have a question about this: $y-x=(y-a)-(x-a) = y-a-x+a = y-x$. I personally would never be able to infer from information in the question that $(y-a)-(x-a)=y-x$. Because the question says it is a geometric series, it would never occur to me to subtract rather than divide. Of course computationally you are correct, but how were you able to come up with this equation in the first place? Thanks.

Comment: Fair question. One way of reasoning could be: since we want to try to rewrite $y-x$ in some form that depends only on $y$ and $a$ one obvious observation is that $x$ need to be turned into something else. Now there are not many realtions regarding $x$ in our setting, so we need to exploit the geometric series property. Explicitating it into the equation $y-a = r*(x-a)$ we saw that the factor $x-a$ that may be useful. Then it comes down to add it into $y-x$ and rebalancing the equation. Indeed, in proofs you often encounter the trick of addig $(a-a)=0$ to an equation. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Since $x-a = \frac{y-a}{r}$, then $x=\frac{y-a}{r}+a$, so wouldn't the equation become $y-x=y-[(x-a)+a]$ instead of $y-x=y-(x-a)+a$? Thanks.

Comment: @ronald-christenkkson you are absolutely correct, I've corrected it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

About your solution - it is correct but it seems quite messy and difficult to follow. If you don't mind, I'll propose another one.

First of all, you don't need these $-a$'s - they just make the solution more messy. So I will let $u=x-a, v=y-a, w=z-a$. Now we need to prove that $2v$ is the harmonic mean of $v-u$ and $v-w$.

Let $r$ be the common ratio of the geometric mean. Therefore we can express $u$ and $w$ in terms of $v$ and $r$ only:
$$u=\frac{v}{r}$$
$$w=vr$$

The harmonic mean $HM$ of two numbers $A$ and $B$ is defined as:
$$HM(A;B)=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}}=\frac{2AB}{A+B}$$
Now, simply plug $A=v-u=v-\frac{v}{r}=v\left(\frac{r-1}{r}\right)$ and $B=v-w=v-vr=v\left(1-r\right)=-v\left(r-1\right)$ above and simplify:
$$HM(v-u; v-w)=\frac{2v\left(\frac{r-1}{r}\right)\left[-v\left(r-1\right)\right]}{v\left(\frac{r-1}{r}\right)-v\left(r-1\right)}=\frac{-2v^2\frac{(r-1)^2}{r}}{v(r-1)\left(\frac{1}{r}-1\right)}=\frac{-2v^2\frac{(r-1)^2}{r}}{v(r-1)\frac{1-r}{r}}=2v.$$
We proved that:
$$HM(v-u; v-w)=2v.$$